# How expensive is a var that is/can-be closed on compared to an Ember.get()?

Tags: javascript, performance, ember.js

Which is more expensive, for various values of x?

```
bob: function(){
  var result = 1;
  var has_a_garbage_collection_cost = this.get('someProperty');
  function() {
     for (i=0;i<x;i++) {
       result = result * has_a_garbage_collection_cost;
     }
  }
  return result;
}.property()
```

or

```
bob: function(){
  var result = 1;
  function() {
     for (i=0;i<x;i++) {
       result = result * this.get('someProperty');
     }
  }
  return result;
}.property()
```

I'm pretty sure from playing around with Chrome's timeline and some interrelated properties that excessively fire each other that the second one is faster when x = 1, but I don't know how to actually benchmark because there is no way to control the garbage collector.

### EDIT:

the above code didn't properly illustrate my point and some people misunderstood. [This jsperf](http://jsperf.com/garbagetest/2) clearly illustrates the garbage collection cost of using a var for a reference that will be used in a closure. Thanks to kingpin2k for the initial cut at a jsperf (but his didn't actually have a closure, so the var version was much faster).

Comment: This sounds like a ridiculous micro-optimization to me.

Comment: Well, obviously running the function only once will be faster than running it a hundred times. I don't see what garbage collection has to do with this, do you think that allocating a single tiny variable would make much difference?

Comment: Or, wait, you're not even calling that function expression? Then not computing `this.get('someProperty');` would be faster than computing it.

Comment: bergi, the function is purely to illustrate a point. Which is that if a computed property is fired a (ridiculous) number of times the garbage collection of vars that have to be kept around because they are used in a closure becomes significant.

Comment: @Mathletics 99% of the time it would be, unfortunately I have a set of related computed properties that fire a large number of times before they settle. Hopefully I figure out how to get them to fire fewer times, in the meantime I'm stuck reducing the impact of how often they fire.

Comment: @Mathletics after playing with jsperf I take back agreeing that it is almost always a ridiculous micro-optimization. The effect is actually quite large http://jsperf.com/garbagetest/2. If you have noticable lag in your Ember UI and a lot of properties firing is the culprit, removing vars from computed properties (if they are closed on, ie, if you use them in a map or a forEach or anything else that involves a closure) will actually make a difference. Who'd'a thunk?

Answer (score 0):

It's actually closer than I expected, honestly the better way would just be to pass it in so it isn't brought in with closure.

http://jsperf.com/garbagetest

Comment: my example wasn't clear. In your jsperf, it looks like the var is faster. But here's a version that actually creates a closure on the var, and it clearly shows the garbage collection cost -- the var version is 73% slower. http://jsperf.com/garbagetest/2

Comment: @kinkgin2k, also I suspect that in a property the effect is multiplied somehow. Because even a 70ish % difference isn't enough to explain the speed up I got by removing several single-use vars from some interrelated properties.

Comment: you have to make sure you run it enough times for the garbage collector to fire. On chrome on my machine it often doesn't fire until there are several megabytes of garbage to collect.

Comment: Interesting, the garbage collection effect totally dominates. Using a reference *programatically* multiple times has no effect on the time (nor using the var).

Comment: using a reference multiple times explicitly is completely dwarfed by the var cost as well. I added an answer with all these findings.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to kingpin2k for making a jsperf. His didn't have a closure though, so I edited it to add a closure, and the effect is actually quite large. And it doesn't matter what x is, the cost of a `get` is completely dwarfed by the cost of creating a`var` that has to stick around until the garbage collector runs. Assuming of course that what you are `get`ting is a scalar of some sort.

The [jsperf is here](http://jsperf.com/garbagetest/2)

Sample results:

#### closed-on-var, 5 uses, looped 10 times

```
function v3() {
  var result = 1;
  var has_a_garbage_collection_cost = something.get('something');
  closure = function() {
     for (i=0;i<10;i++) {
       result = result + has_a_garbage_collection_cost;
       result = result + has_a_garbage_collection_cost;
       result = result + has_a_garbage_collection_cost;
       result = result + has_a_garbage_collection_cost;
       result = result + has_a_garbage_collection_cost;
     }
  }
  closure();
  return result;
}
v3(100000);
```

**ops/sec 3,313,948 73% slower**

#### reference,5 uses looped 10 times

```
function r3() {
  var result = 1;
  closure = function() {
     for (i=0;i<10;i++) {
       result = result + something.get('something');
       result = result + something.get('something');
       result = result + something.get('something');
       result = result + something.get('something');
       result = result + something.get('something');
     }
  }
  closure();
  return result;
}
r3(100000);
```

**ops/sec 12,034,223**

### EDIT: Perhaps only relevant on Safari

The big gulf seems to only be on Safari, with single use var & single use reference being almost the same, and multiple use reference being much slower than multiple use of a var on Chrome and Firefox. However this might be that the garbage collector isn't getting counted in the jsperf test harness on chrome, because when I removed several single-use vars from a set of properties that were consistently taking 600ms to run on chrome (measured using chrome's timeline feature) they subsequently took 500ms. It was the GC times on chrome's timeline that feature that gave me the idea to try it.